# Autofac: Issue with loading Module using autofac configuration

Tags: asp.net-core, autofac-module

I am trying to load dependency by Autofac Configuration in my .net core3.1 project.

However, I am getting error at startup.

> The type 'TPrefix.TServiceName.Messaging.MessagingModule,
>   TPrefix.TServiceName.Messaging' could not be found. It may require
>   assembly qualification, e.g. "MyType, MyAssembly".

Could someone kindly help me show the direction, where I am going wrong.

Below are the details -

My autofac.json file:

```
    {
  "defaultAssembly": "",
  "components": [], 
  "modules": [
    {
      "type": "TPrefix.TServiceName.Messaging.MessagingModule, TPrefix.TServiceName.Messaging"
    }
  ]
}
```

My code structure looks like this:

[image]

Hi All,
I am trying to load depemdencies in ***TPrefix.TServiceName.Messaging*** assembly as follows:

```
namespace TPrefix.TServiceName.Messaging
{
    public class MessagingModule : Autofac.Module
    {
        protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
        {
             //Registration code goes here
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My problem was resolved following [this](https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration/xml.html#type-names).